# Array of Struct pointers, get segfault in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

```
#define MAX_SPACES 10
#define MAX_SIMPLE_EVENTS 5000
#define MAX_USER_EVENTS 1000

struct {
  EventSpace* p_spaces[MAX_SPACES];
  SimpleEvent* p_simple_events[MAX_SIMPLE_EVENTS];
  UserEvent* p_user_events[MAX_USER_EVENTS];
}* G_manager;

static void add_space(EventSpace* space){
  static uint16_t index = 0;
  (*G_manager).p_spaces[index] = space;
}
```

After running in gdb got:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400559 in add_space (space=0x7fffffffdf30)

How to impove it?

Comment: You'll have to show how you're allocating memory to be able to determine what's going on.

Comment: You probably don't have p_spaces array member allocated. Ah, forget this. Need coffee.

Comment: @BradBales can i do this in gdb? What way?

Comment: `G_manager`, a pointer,  is `NULL`.  Why expect `(*G_manager)` to work?

Comment: In other words, could you show us the rest of your code?  Specifically, your code where you malloc() or calloc() the memory for everything?

Comment: @chux I am new in c. So I have some not obvious for me problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in the code you're showing, you haven't actually allocated the memory for the structure containing the arrays; you've only created a pointer.  So when you dereference that pointer meaning to write into an instance of the structure, you hit a random memory address and got the relatively tame result of your program crashing.

You could change `G_manager` from a pointer-to-struct to an instance of the struct itself; or you can malloc a buffer big enough for the structure and assign that buffer to `G_manager`